# Black areas when rendering in Radeon 7870 GPU

Tags: gpu, artifacts

[image]

Hello everyone, I have a problem with the GPU (msi radeon hd 7870 2gb oc edition), practically in some scenes the rendering with the gpu form some black parts, which are not shown if I render the same scene with an xfx rx 480.
What could be the problem?

***I installing Blender version 2.77 as user Mike Pan said, and the problem is solved.***

Comment: Are the scenes that result in a black screen, scenes with a lot of objects or detail? I'm guessing that it could be a case of your graphics card possibly running out of memory when rendering.

Comment: 7870 is GCN 1.0 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_7000_Series), which is no longer supported by Blender as of 2.78c.  You'll need a GCN2.0 architecture video card to use GPU rendering.

Comment: If I install an older version of blender, would I be able to render or I must change my video card?

Comment: Thanks Mike Pan for the tip! I installed version 2.77 and confirm that it works perfectly. The rendering has gone from 3 minutes with the CPU to 30 seconds with the GPU! You saved my work!